# What is the difference between a first and second degree taylor ploynomial?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For taylor polynomials, what is the difference between the first and second degree taylor polynomial? For example, a function $f(x, y) = x+y^{2}$. Does it make the approximation more precise or is there more to it?

Comment: The first degree Taylor polynomial is a linear approximation of your function.  The second degree polynomial is a quadratic approximation.  It will give you a more accurate approximation over a larger range of inputs.

Comment: @DougM does that mean for all first degree taylor polynomials will have a degree of 1 even if the degree is greater than 1?

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, then for $n \ge m$, the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial of $f$ is $f$ itself. [Not sure if this is what you are asking.]